# Typing generic state functions in Python

Tags: python, generics, state-machine, type-hinting, pylance

I haven't been able to make either pylance or mypy happy with typing a generic state function. If I hardcode the state machine (not using a generic base class), I get no errors. In my actual implementation, the generic class is not also an abstract class, but I get the same problem, so the issue is unrelated to that.

Here's the code. Mind you, the implementation here is unrelated to what my state machine does. I just created something minimal that shows the same problems. I've also struggled to make type checking happy having a particular state function designate the end of the stream (e.g. `state_done`), instead of looking for the value `None`.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional, Callable
import random


_T = TypeVar("_T")
StateFunc = Optional[Callable[[_T], Optional["StateFunc"]]]


class GenericMachine(Generic[_T], ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self._state: StateFunc[_T]

    def run(self) -> None:
        while self._state is not None:
            self._state = self._state(self.get_next_event())

    @abstractmethod
    def get_next_event(self) -> _T:
        pass


class Catch(GenericMachine[float]):
    _MyStateFunc = StateFunc[float]

    def __init__(self):
        print("person has ball")
        self._state: Catch._MyStateFunc = self._state_person_with_ball  # ERROR 1

    def get_next_event(self) -> float:
        return random.random()

    def _state_person_with_ball(self, r: float) -> Catch._MyStateFunc:
        if r < 0.2:
            return None
        print("ball in air")
        return self._state_ball_in_air  # ERROR 2

    def _state_ball_in_air(self, r: float) -> Catch._MyStateFunc:
        print("dog has ball")
        return self._state_dog_with_ball  # ERROR 2

    def _state_dog_with_ball(self, r: float) -> Catch._MyStateFunc:
        if r < 0.2:
            return None
        print("person has ball")
        return self._state_person_with_ball  # ERROR 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Catch().run()
```

EDIT: I realize that mypy won't get past the recursive type definition. I get similar errors on mypy when I just declare `StateFunc` to return a `Callable`.

Pylance reports the following for ERROR 1 (via VS Code):

```
Cannot assign member "_state" for type "Catch"
  Expression of type "(r: float) -> (_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to member "_state" of class "Catch"
    Type "(r: float) -> (_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None"
      Type "(r: float) -> (_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None"
      Type cannot be assigned to type "None"
        Function return type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" is incompatible with type "StateFunc | None"
          Type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to type "StateFunc | None"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(variable) _state: (r: float) -> Unknown
```

And it reports the following for ERROR 2 (via VS Code):

```
Expression of type "(r: float) -> (_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to return type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None"
  Type "(r: float) -> (_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None"
    Type "(r: float) -> (_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None"
    Type cannot be assigned to type "None"
      Function return type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" is incompatible with type "StateFunc | None"
        Type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None | None" cannot be assigned to type "StateFunc | None"
          Type "(_p0: float) -> StateFunc | None" cannot be assigned to type "StateFunc | None"PylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(parameter) self: Catch
```

Any idea how to make Pylance happy?

UPDATE: The problem goes away if I define StateFunc as follows:

`StateFunc = Optional[Callable[[_T], Any]]`

Comment: `mypy` doesn't allow cyclic definitions. `StateFunc` cannot be defined in terms of itself. (This is beyond the standard Python issue of the name `StateFunc` being undefined in the RHS of the expression, which the use of `"StateFunc"` resolves.)

Comment: The use of `self._state_*` instead of `Catch._state` may also be an issue, as the former is a bound method (type `method`), rather than an ordinary function (type `function`). The signatures of each are different, which could lead to the error reported by VS Code.

Comment: Maybe define the state funcs as instances of a class whose `__call__` returns its own type, rather than as methods?

Comment: @chepner, Pylance does allow cyclic type definitions and is not giving me an error there. I do have to quote the cyclic reference, though, despite using __future__ annotations.

Comment: @Samwise, yes, that's how state functions work.

Comment: @chepner, I just tried replacing `self._state_*` with `Catch._state_*`, but I get the same errors. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JoeLapp Right, because `__future__.annotations` only applies to annotations, not type-alias definitions. You mentioned `mypy` at the top of the question, and this is the only relevant error for `mypy`, because it doesn't even get to the actual type-checking because oof it.

Comment: I can't be of any assistance with pylance, sorry :)

Comment: @chepner, oh right, I did mention Mypy. My workaround with mypy was to not declare the return value in StateFunc, but I still get analogous errors. But you're right, this code here breaks on mypy sooner than I mentioned.